# Parsing HTML with cURL POST

Tags: curl

I'm sending `POST` request to some link with valid username and password.

I use this command: `curl -X POST -F 'username=test@me.com' -F 'password=123' http://my.site.com/login`

but it got `Moved Temporarily. Redirecting to /`

How can I redirect with cURL ?

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Server: nginx
Date: Sun, 09 Oct 2016 07:43:26 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 58
Connection: close
Vary: Accept
Location: /
Set-Cookie: connect.sid=s%3A%2FU%2FG5YeSNkjkaA%2Fet4evdmgj.QIGEGtrJQxNcNx1bdF6QzshqsEXn3hys1V2mkyuw3nY; Path=/; Expires=Sun, 09 Oct 2016 08:13:26 GMT; HttpOnly

<p>Moved Temporarily. Redirecting to <a href="/">/</a></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

`curl`'s `-L` (`--location`) option follows a redirected URL:

```
curl -LX POST ...
```

But the caveat is that, this will follow redirections after login. If the login page redirects to another login page where you need to (re)submit the same POST request, then you need to use the `--location-trusted` option to make all the redirected URLs as trusted, otherwise `curl` will send the POST authentication info only to the initial URL. So if you trust the redirected URL, do:

```
curl -L --location-trusted -X POST ...
```

Comment: i must add `/` after `-LX` ?

Comment: @MehranGoudarzi No, just do `curl -LX POST -F 'username=test@me.com' -F 'password=123' http://my.site.com/login`, if other things are correct then this should work.

Comment: i did it but seems not login . i login with Chrome and see view source ,  that Different from curl show .

Comment: @MehranGoudarzi Check my edits.

Comment: @MehranGoudarzi Make sure the HTML directives are correct, otherwise this should work.

Comment: HTML directives work because i do it with `burpsute` and after i click `Follow redirection` it work . but seems redirection not work on curl .

Comment: I think the authentication has succeeded and has been converted into a session cookie which you must preserve on the redirection. Add a dummy cookie jar with `-b ''` to get the `-L` to parse the cookie in the response and present it in the redirect.